# XAML MultiBinding StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I cannot figure out my MultiBinding StringFormat behavior. I have a DataContext which defines a numeric range via the properties MinIncl and MaxIncl. I want to create a tooltip using MultiBinding to create a tip like "1.0 to 999.0". I try the following code:

```
         <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock>
              <TextBlock.Text>
                 <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:F1} to {1:F1}">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedTrainingScriptParameter.MinimumInclusive"/>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedTrainingScriptParameter.MaximumInclusive"/>
                 </MultiBinding>
              </TextBlock.Text>
           </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
     </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

The resulting tooltip is "to 999.0 1.0". So it has reversed the range and put the word "to" first.

If I remove the spaces and try "{}{0:F1}to{1:F1}", I get the right answer: "1.0to999.0".

Seriously, why does the whitespace and word "to" break this thing?

Thanks.

-reilly.

Comment: I have tested the XAML you posted, and (at least for me), my tooltip shows "1.0 to 999.0" (tried with .NET 4.5 and .NET 3.5). Therefore, the `StringFormat` you use is OK. The problem seems to be outside of the code that you show in your question.

Comment: @fmunkert: You were correct. My tooltip was on a DoubleUpDown control from the Extended WPF Toolkit (http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DoubleUpDown). When I used the same binding on a TextBox, it works fine. I never thought to check the control...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you don't need a multi, just use the same `TextBlock` instead like;

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="{Binding Path=SelectedTrainingScriptParameter.MinimumInclusive}"/>
   <Run Text="to"/>
   <Run Text="{Binding Path=SelectedTrainingScriptParameter.MaximumInclusive}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Or if you really want to use it as is;

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>    
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} to {1}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedTrainingScriptParameter.MinimumInclusive" />
            <Binding Path="SelectedTrainingScriptParameter.MaximumInclusive" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

As to the weird whitespace thing, no idea sorry. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: W: I used your suggestion as the fix and it works. If you look at my comment to fmunkert above, turns out the odd formatting was being done to me by the enclosing free control. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no worries, when I looked at yours it looked correct too anyway, but I didn't have time to test anything, one cool thing about this stuff though is there's usually always another way.